# How do i list only the subdirectories of a specified directory?

Tags: php

Please in php how do get a list of sub-directories in a specified directory without showing the parent directory? Already, i have something like this:

```
$subdirs = array_filter(glob('mydir/*'), 'is_dir');
foreach($subdirs as $s){
 echo $s.'<br>';
}
```

This is what i have as sample output:
mydir/accounts,
mydir/payment

I only want this as output:
accounts,
payment

Please, how do i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to return the last folder (stripping `mydir` off).

```
$subdirs = array_filter(glob('mydir/*'), 'is_dir');
foreach($subdirs as $s){
    echo basename($s) . '<br>';
}
```

**Note:** this won't work for multiple subdirectories, and you'd be better to strip off the `mydir/` part using `str_replace()`:

```
$subdirs = array_filter(glob('mydir/*'), 'is_dir');
foreach($subdirs as $s){
    echo str_replace('mydir/', '', $s) . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
$subdirs = array_map('basename', glob('mydir/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
```

Or if you need to use `$subdirs` later and retain the full path:

```
$subdirs = glob('mydir/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach(array_map('basename', $subdirs) as $s) {
```

Answer (score 0):

basename() worked form me.

```
$subdirs = array_filter(glob('mydir/*'), 'is_dir');
foreach($subdirs as $s){
 echo basename($s) . '<br>';
}
```

This also worked for me:

```
foreach($subdirs as $s){
 echo str_replace("mydir/", "", $s).'<br>';
}
```